# how do i seperately identify my 5.1 on board sound from 3.5mm jack on front of tower?

Tags: audio-jack

i have a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 LTS. my motherboard has built in 5.1 on the backside and my computer case has additional usb, esata, and audio ports. the 5.1 sound works fine. however, when i plug in my headphones to the jack on my case, ubuntu recognizes my headphones as the default analog audio device and no longer recognizes my 5.1. i need to have these identified as 2 separate devices so i can route voice chat through the head phones and regular sound through the 5.1.

Comment: So you not only want to enable headphones and “regular” audio output simultaneously, but you also want to be able to choose which output a program uses? I'd be surprised if that's possible, at the same time I know for sure Linux knows a way. I'm eager for an answer here.

Comment: Try `pavucontrol`, it does have a choice *(both "default" and per-application)* which device to output to. It might help or not, depending on hw.

Comment: just tried pavucontrol, unfortunately the exact same issue is happening inside of that application as well. thx tho.